# Pivot table filter in vba not working properly

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code to pick a date and change the filter of a Pivot Table to reflect the related info. But some times this works and some times it gives me the

> Error 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error

This is driving me crazy, and I don´t know what's happening, especially because this code works and then it doesn't, without any change.

```
Dim DataVenda As Date
DataVenda = InputBox("Data de Vendas (dd/mm):")

ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select
With Selection
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DinTblResumoDiario").PivotFields("Data:").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DinTblResumoDiario").PivotFields("Data:").CurrentPage = DataVenda
End With
```

The error is in the last command: `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DinTblResumoDiario").PivotFields("Data:").CurrentPage = DataVenda`

Comment: You will feel much better when you throw that `ActiveSheet` and put instead the sheet's codename explicitly, :)

Comment: Have you tried making sure that the page you are trying to set it to exists within the filters? Also, try setting "EnableMultiplePageItems = False".

Comment: Do you know for sure, that there are always items for the input? AFAIK, the pivot table raises an error if you try to select a value that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Yes, the value is right. Even because after I try for some minutes the same value it works, and then doesn´t again, sometimes I quit the file and try again 10 minutes later, it work for 2/3 values, then stop working. Its weird. I will try the code given bellow by Shai Rado and update if it works properly. Thanks.

Comment: @Frederico  have you tried the code in my answer below ? is it working like you intended ?

Comment: Hi @ShaiRado, thanks for the answer! Yes, I am using your code since sunday, and its working perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: @Frederico so please mark my answer as "answer", click on the **V** next to my answer and it will turn green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like written above, it's better to avoid using `ActiveSheet`, `Select` and `Selection`, and use fully qualified objects instead.

The code below I use an object of type `PivotTable` to define and set the Pivot Table, and also for the `PivotField`.

I also added another type of `InputBox` that forces the user to enter a value in a `Date` format.

**Note**: there is a chance that the value selected in the `InputBox` isn't found anywhere inside the Pivot Table, so I've added a way to check it in the code below.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub OccupancyPivot()

Dim wsSheet             As Worksheet
Dim PT                  As PivotTable
Dim PTFld               As PivotField
Dim DataVenda           As Date

' use this type of Input Box to force the user to enter a date format
DataVenda = Application.InputBox("Data de Vendas (dd/mm):", "Select date", FormatDateTime(Date, vbShortDate), Type:=1)       

Set wsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- modify "Sheet1" to your Pivot's sheet name

On Error Resume Next
Set PT = wsSheet.PivotTables("DinTblResumoDiario") ' set the PivotTable    
On Error GoTo 0
If PT Is Nothing Then ' "DinTblResumoDiario" Pivot Table doesn't exist
    MsgBox "Pivot Table 'DinTblResumoDiario' doesn't exist!"
Else ' "DinTblResumoDiario" Pivot Table exists
    Set PTFld = PT.PivotFields("Data:") ' <-- set the pivot field    
    PTFld.ClearAllFilters

    On Error Resume Next
    PTFld.CurrentPage = DataVenda ' Error line if DataVenda isn't valid (no value inside Pivot Table matches it)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Filter Didn't get applied, no value inside Pivot Table matches your selection"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End If

End Sub
```